# How to derive the maximum power transfer theorem using the relation p=v²/R?

Tags: voltage, power, resistors, thevenin, physics

In most derivations of the Maximum power transfer theorem the derivation is done using the relation of power :

P = i²R
And on further derivation it comes out to be
Pmax = Vth²/4Rth

If I derive the power from the relation p= vth²/Rth

It's clearly wrong
My logic is as follows :
The voltage across the load resistance is Thevenin voltage Vth , and it's resistance is RL but for Maximum power to be transferred, RL must be equal to Rth therefore the formula. Can anyone explain what am I missing here? (Actually I derived it intuitively in the exam, it turned out to be a blunder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *My logic is as follows : The voltage across the load resistance is
> Thevenin voltage Vth*

Your logic is flawed...

- \$V_{TH}\$ is the equivalent open circuit voltage before you add any load.
- When you add a load equivalent to the Thevenin resistance of the source, the terminal voltage across that load drops to half the original Thevenin voltage --> \$V_{TH}\$/2
- Hence squaring \$V_{TH}\$/2 produces \$V_{TH}^2\$/4

Comment: Ah I get it, since the load resistance is equal to the thevenin resistance, the voltage drops half of it across the load and that squared gives the result. Thanks